# Range Migration Algorithm in FMCW MIMO RADAR

Tags: algorithms, frequency-domain, radar, mimo

I’m using a FMCW MIMO radar [77-79 GHz] with a virtual linear array made of 48 channels.

I’m wondering if the adaptation of the range migration algorithm (typically used in SAR processing) is feasible for this kind of radar. My concern regards the few numbers of points (48) along the track (azimuth) dimension.

Comment: well, how large are your range cells?

Comment: I have 4096 samples per chirp, each range cell is 7.8 cm [corresponding to 6.51KHz]. The 48 virtual antennas are placed each 1.91 mm [lambda/2]. So my raw data matrix is 48x4096.